# How to print a list instead of a list of lists

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercise where certain classes based on their subject and number are classified as either upper or lower. I was able to get the correct classification of upper and lower level classes but my output seems to be a list of lists. Below is the expected output which is simply a list. My code is based on methods I have learned so far in my module.

Expected Output

```
['PSYCH 412', 'MATH 300', 'MATH 404', 'ENG 201', 'PSYCH 508', 'ENG 220']
```

Can someone help me figure out how to get my output to be a list instead of a list of lists?  Thank you.

```
classes = ["MATH 150", "PSYCH 111", "PSYCH 313", "PSYCH 412", "MATH 300", "MATH 404", "MATH 206", "ENG 100", "ENG 103", "ENG 201", "PSYCH 508", "ENG 220", "ENG 125", "ENG 124"]
upper = [] #empty list
lower = [] #empty list

for w in classes:
    sub = w.split()
    if "MATH" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 300:
        upper.append(sub)
    elif "ENG" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 200:
        upper.append(sub)
    elif "PSYCH" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 400:
        upper.append(sub)
    else:
        lower.append(sub)

print("Upper Level Courses:", upper)
```

My Output

```
Upper Level Courses: [['PSYCH', '412'], ['MATH', '300'], ['MATH', '404'], ['ENG', '201'], ['PSYCH', '508'], ['ENG', '220']]
```

Comment: Append `w`, not `sub` : `upper.append(w)`

Comment: If you want to keep your data structure intact then use this as your print statement : print("Upper Level Courses:", [" ".join(x) for x in upper])

Comment: @Akash what does this mean?

Comment: [" ".join(x) for x in upper]) this? This is just a list comprehension for iterating through the list of list and join the elements of inner list with a space and create the desired list. If you asking about "keeping the DS intact" ,by that i mean if he wants to create list of lists but want to print a single list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is close, just instead of `sub` append `w` to `upper` or `lower`:

```
classes = ["MATH 150", "PSYCH 111", "PSYCH 313", "PSYCH 412", "MATH 300", "MATH 404", "MATH 206", "ENG 100", "ENG 103", "ENG 201", "PSYCH 508", "ENG 220", "ENG 125", "ENG 124"]
upper = [] #empty list
lower = [] #empty list

for w in classes:
    sub = w.split()
    if "MATH" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 300:
        upper.append(w)
    elif "ENG" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 200:
        upper.append(w)
    elif "PSYCH" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 400:
        upper.append(w)
    else:
        lower.append(w)

print("Upper Level Courses:", upper)
```

Prints:

```
Upper Level Courses: ['PSYCH 412', 'MATH 300', 'MATH 404', 'ENG 201', 'PSYCH 508', 'ENG 220']
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `sub` object is a list type, that's why in the results it's a list. You could concentrate the sub list as a string, or just use `w` object and then append to the upper/lower list.

```
classes = ["MATH 150", "PSYCH 111", "PSYCH 313", "PSYCH 412", "MATH 300", "MATH 404", "MATH 206", "ENG 100", "ENG 103", "ENG 201", "PSYCH 508", "ENG 220", "ENG 125", "ENG 124"]
upper = [] #empty list
lower = [] #empty list

for w in classes:
    sub = w.split()
    if "MATH" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 300:
        upper.append(" ".join(sub))
    elif "ENG" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 200:
        upper.append(" ".join(sub))
    elif "PSYCH" in sub and int(sub[1]) >= 400:
        upper.append(" ".join(sub))
    else:
        lower.append(" ".join(sub))

print("Upper Level Courses:", upper)
```

You could also use `List Comprehensions` to rewrite your code like the following:

```
classes = ["MATH 150", "PSYCH 111", "PSYCH 313", "PSYCH 412", "MATH 300", "MATH 404", "MATH 206", "ENG 100", "ENG 103", "ENG 201", "PSYCH 508", "ENG 220", "ENG 125", "ENG 124"]

upper = [c for c in classes if ("MATH" in c and int(c.split()[1])>=300) or ("ENG" in c and int(c.split()[1])>=200) or ("PSYCH" in c and int(c.split()[1])>=400) ]
lower = [c for c in classes if c not in upper]
```

Hope it helps.